# When earphones are plugged in don't play notification sound through the speakers

Tags: android, audio, notifications

I'm adding sound to certain notifications in my app, like so:

```
Notification notification = ...
...
notification.sound = Uri.parse(...);
```

When the notification sound plays it does so through the speakers even when headphones are plugged to the phone, and so the sound is played in both the speakers and headphones.

Is there a way to play the sound only through the headphones if it's plugged in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> #### Is there a way to play the sound only through the headphones if it's
>
> #### plugged in?

For now its not possible to forcefully play sound through **headphones**

### see this google issue tracker [Notifications are played through external speaker when headphones are plugged in](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16667) and discussion.

---

### For checking headphone is plugged in

Register Receiver

```
ReceiveBroadcast receiver=new ReceiveBroadcast();       
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG));
```

> onReceive() code

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     if (intent.hasExtra("state")){
         if (headsetConnected && intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 0){
             headsetConnected = false;
            
         } else if (!headsetConnected && intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 1){
            headsetConnected = true;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the google discussion. Seems that there's no value in knowing when the phones are plugged in if I have no control of where the notification sound is coming through.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AudioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn()` for checking if the headset are plugged in.

And you need  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />`

example :

```
AudioManager am1 = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am1.isWiredHeadsetOn();
```

Comment: Thanks, but knowing if the headset is plugged in doesn't help me if I have no control of where to play the notification sound from.